# How to filter by sub-object in Rally 2 SDK

Tags: rally

I'm trying to query for user stories whose release start date is greater than a particular date. Is it possible to do this using the "filters" config rather than querying all stories and then checking manually?

Is this valid? :

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'UserStory',
    context: {
        project: '/project/xxxx'
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    fetch: ['Rank', 'FormattedID', 'Release'],
    filters: [
        {
            property: 'Release.ReleaseStartDate',
            operator: '>',
            value: '2012-10-10'
        }
    ]
});
```

It doesn't work, just fetches all records.

Comment: That should work.  If you inspect your request in the network tab of your browser do you see query=(Release.ReleaseStartDate > 2012-10-10)?  If not this seems like a defect...

Comment: Ok never mind. It does work. I was actually using a comboBox value in the "value" property. Turns out I didn't convert it to a proper DateTime format and hence the comparison was failing and returning all records.

Comment: Hi Vikram, could you post your observation as an answer? That helps the forum know the question's been taken care of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted above **does** work. I was actually using a comboBox value in the "value" property. Turns out I didn't convert it to a proper DateTime format and hence the comparison was failing and returning all records.

In my case I had to use Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString in order to compare the value in the combobox.